# How to exclude data entry in ArrayList using adapter from firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 columns in my firebase (kamar and kamar_terisi), every time a user rents a room, the room key automatically enters the kamar_terisi column, and I want to make it not appear on this list,

[image: This is my firebase,]
[It must be not appear in list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNTNj.jpg)

This my code

```
private void showKamar() {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Kamar");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    final Kamar kamar = snapshot.getValue(Kamar.class);
                    kamar.setKey(snapshot.getKey());
                    list.add(kamar);
                    isi_reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                final KamarIsi kamarIsi = snapshot.getValue(KamarIsi.class);
                                kamarIsi.setKey(snapshot.getKey());
                                isi_reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        if (snapshot.hasChild(kamarIsi.getKey())) {
                                            list2.add(kamarIsi);
                                        } else if (!kamarIsi.getId_user().equals("")) {}
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
            }
            kamarListAdapter = new KamarListAdapter(getContext(), list, list2);
            sewakamar.setAdapter(kamarListAdapter);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println(databaseError.getDetails()+" "+databaseError.getMessage());
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to put one more field like `isRoomAlreadyRented` or `is RoomAvailable`. Update this when room gets hired and check this field before adding items to the `ListAdapter`. Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Comment: @Vishnu that's what i need, thanks bro